# Android - MenuItem.setIcon() not working when adding fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menuitem, android-menu

In my mainFragment I have menuItem for notifications, when I receive a notification, I change the icon of the menuItem (to icon with a badge) and it works fine; then I click the menuItem to show the list of notifications (add fragment). when I go back to the mainFragment, the menuItem icon doesn't change anymore when I receive a notification

here is my code on the main fragment:

```
private MenuItem menuItem;

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_item);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


public void methodCalledToChangeIcon() {
    if (condition)
        menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action));
    else
        menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_checked));
}
```

any help please.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more. Your question seems to be unclear.

Comment: @WijaySharma I update the qst